# Passing variables to Class from HTML

Tags: html, flash, actionscript-3, class, variables

I want to pass some image names and numbers as string to my flash, so in html file I have :

```
src="imgvid-00.swf?imageData=image00/00.gif,3,image00/01.gif,6,image00/02.gif,10"
```

in flash swf I have a class like this:

```
package src{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash....

    public class imgvid extends MovieClip {
        public var dataBANK:Array = new Array();        

        public function imgvid():void {
            //put all var in Array dataBANK     
        }
    }
}
```

How I do this? 
I try :
`public var paramObj = this.loaderInfo.parameters;` 
but that does not work ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass paramters  in as flashvars. query parameters are not passed into flash in the way you have in your example. Read up about flashvars here:

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16417.html

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="550" height="400" id="myFlashMovie" align="middle">
    <param name="movie" value="myFlashMovie.swf" />
    <param name=FlashVars value="myVariable=Hello%20World&mySecondVariable=Goodbye">
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="myFlashMovie.swf" width="550" height="400">
        <param name="movie" value="myFlashMovie.swf" />
        <param name=FlashVars value="myVariable=Hello%20World&mySecondVariable=Goodbye">
    <!--<![endif]-->
        <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
            <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
        </a>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

using swf object to do all this makes it easier than doing it manually as above

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Comment: .. wow .. thanks a lot.. But how about class? How I can get them in my class? `public var paramObj = this.loaderInfo.parameters;` is not working ..

Comment: you should use LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;